# can you enable accessibility zoom whith the command line?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, accessibility

Is, there any way for me to use the command line to enable the accessibility zoom or to assign a shortcut for it? or is there a better option to make the screen zoom in and out by pressing a key combination?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl with + ?  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enable "Zoom"  in "Settings" - "Accessibility", a shortcut key for zooming is automatically enabled. Hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to zoom in, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out. The Super Key is the Windows Key on many keyboards, and on Macs, it will be the <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> key.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, somehow I missed that. But if it's enabled and fully zoomed out, there's a glitch where it doesn't erase the old mouse curser and leaves behind a trail of mouse cursers. So I don't think it's a good Idea to leave it on the entire time.